# How to can I view a simple text file via adb shell?

Tags: android

How can I view a simple text file via adb or adb shell ?
I know there is fileExplorer that comes with ADT but its not very handy, I have pull a file every time, then open it,

is there a quick way on the command line ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`adb shell cat /sdcard/file.txt`

`cat` is the command for displaying text files in linux.

*usage: cat [-beflnstv] [-] [file ...]*

Comment: is there any other text viewer in adb shell?

Answer (score 2):

cat is the command which is useful to open text files in adb.

```
cat txtfile
```

or

```
cat txtfile.text
```